# How to show description of all methods in Eclipse for a jsp file?

Tags: eclipse, jsp

For a JSP file, Eclipse does not show description of all methods. For example if I type **<%out.%>** . It will only show description of certain methods like Writer methods, unlike Netbeans where every method of *out* has a description popping out. *out.print* has a description in Netbeans and all other methods. Usually the methods that have a color of green in Content Assist does not have a description. How do I do it for all jsp methods in Eclipse? I want to make it like Netbeans style where all methods will show its pop-out description.

[image: Screenshot in Netbeans]

[image: Screenshot in Eclipse]

Comment: It might be because your project or your Eclipse configuration misses JavaDoc or source attachment for the JRE methods, so the completion only use the data from the .class file, and that doesn't include parameter names nor JavaDoc. See other posts related to attaching Javadoc.

Comment: Does that mean that every Java project that I create in Netbeans has an included Javadoc? Because it always shows description of every methods for every java project that I make. How about you? Does every method in your Ecipse Java project pops out a description every time like in Netbeans?

Comment: Is this a Maven project? If so, you can try to go to Preferences > Maven and check "Download artifact sources" and "Download artifact javadoc". Then right-click on project > Maven > Update configuration... and you should get the source automatically available.

Comment: No it is just a simple jsp project. I do not know Maven yet.